# Does anybody have a KSQL query that counts event in a topic on a per hour basis?

Tags: ksqldb

I am new to KSQL and I am trying to get the counts of the events in a topic group per hour. If not I would settle for counting the events in the topic. Then I could change the query to work in a windowing basis. The timestamp is the
To give more context let's assume my topic is called messenger and the events are in JSON format. And here is a sample message:

```
{"name":"Won","message":"This message is from Won","ets":1642703358124}
Partition:0 Offset:69 Timestamp:1642703359427
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a stream over the topic:

```sql
CREATE STREAM my_stream (NAME VARCHAR, MESSAGE VARCHAR)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my_topic', FORMAT='JSON');
```

Then use a `TUMBLING` window aggregation and a dummy `GROUP BY` field:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(WINDOWSTART,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','Europe/London')
         AS WINDOW_START_TS,
       COUNT(*) AS RECORD_CT
  FROM my_stream
        WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 HOURS)
  GROUP BY 1
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

If you want to override the timestamp being picked up from the message timestamp and [use a custom timestamp field](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/use-a-custom-timestamp-column/) (I can see `ets` in your sample) you would do that in the stream definition:

```sql
CREATE STREAM my_stream (NAME VARCHAR, MESSAGE VARCHAR, ETS BIGINT)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my_topic', FORMAT='JSON', TIMESTAMP='ets');
```

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2020/09/08/counting-the-number-of-messages-in-a-kafka-topic/